# cannot read property inner html of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
var eventFired = function ( type ) {
var n = $('#demo_info')[0];
n.innerHTML += '<div>'+type+' event - '+new Date().getTime()+'</div>';
n.scrollTop = n.scrollHeight;      
}
$('#example')
.on( 'order.dt',  function () { eventFired( 'Order' ); } )
.on( 'search.dt', function () { eventFired( 'Search' ); } )
.on( 'page.dt',   function () { eventFired( 'Page' ); } )
.dataTable();
} );
</script>
```

error type:-cannot read property inner html of undefined type.javascript error

Comment: do you have element with id 'demo_info' ..?

Answer (score 2):

You mix up JavaScript and jQuery. 
Use:

```
var n = $('#demo_info');
n.html('<div>'+type+' event - '+new Date().getTime()+'</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery gets single element not array

use this

```
var n = $('#demo_info');
```

instead of

```
var n = $('#demo_info')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this , hope it helps :) :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
var eventFired = function ( type ) {
$('#demo_info').each(function(){
this.innerHTML += '<div>'+type+' event - '+new Date().getTime()+'</div>';
this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight;
});   
}
$('#example')
.on( 'order.dt',  function () { eventFired( 'Order' ); } )
.on( 'search.dt', function () { eventFired( 'Search' ); } )
.on( 'page.dt',   function () { eventFired( 'Page' ); } )
.dataTable();
} );
</script>
```